# Update query - incrementing int field value and if statement

Tags: mysql

I am currently learning SQL through my local mysql db. I have a table named `transactions` that has 5 fields. I am running an `update` query for column where `name` = `jane`. Essentially, I want to integrate an if statement when `date_created – tran_date =  1 month` to reset values to `transaction = 0`, `tran_date = 0000-00-00`, and change `date_created` to the new current date.

Query(help)- UPDATED

```
UPDATE transactions SET transactions = transactions + 1, tran_date = CURDATE()  WHERE name = 'jim'
```

Create tables and set values:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  date_created DATE,
  name varchar(20),
  transactions int(6), 
  tran_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO transactions
(date_created, name, transactions, tran_date)
VALUES
(NOW(), 'jim', 0, 0000-00-00),
(NOW(), 'jane', 0, 0000-00-00);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update`syntax is wrong:

```
UPDATE transactions SET transactions = transactions + 1, tran_date = CURDATE()  WHRE name = 'jim'
```

You have not to use `AND` in set clause. You must use a comma at this place.

Comment: Oh a rookie mistake. I overlooked that. Thanks. I updated the question. any hints or ideas for last part?